# Spring boot - how to configure JSP view in JBOSS 7?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss7.x

I'm newbie in spring boot.I am facing a problem while deploying war in Jboss 7.1.1. When i tried to deploy WAR in tomcat, it's running smoothly but when i switched to JBOSS 7, it has stopped application to deploy.

As we know that JBOSS doesn't allow us '/' so to achieve '/*' using dispatcherServlet and try to register it problematically in my @SpringBootApplication annotated class as given below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
         ServletRegistrationBean registration = new     ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet(), "/*");
         registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
         return registration;
      } 

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
      return new DispatcherServlet();
     } 

    @Override
     public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException    {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);    
     }  

     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AppSpringBootConfig.class);
     }
    }
```

and added below lines in application.properties file

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
 spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I am using @EnableAutoConfiguration so it should automatically mapped return jsp name with file available inside jsp folder.

Instead it give me an error like  **Cannot forward to error page for request [/login] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false**

Is it possible to override InternalResourceViewResolver?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem with JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21). After installing the Jboss patch jboss-eap-6.4.6-patch.zip the problem does not occur anymore.

After patching I did not need to use the setting server.servlet-path=/*